# How to get build log from msbuild?

Tags: c#, msbuild, cakebuild

I am using the code bellow for compiling my project in cake script and I want to get build log in text file.

```
if(IsRunningOnWindows())
{

  // Use MSBuild
  foreach(string currenproject in projectslocation)
  {
  MSBuild(currenproject, new MSBuildSettings()
  .SetConfiguration(configuration)
  .SetVerbosity(Verbosity.Minimal));

  }

}
```

Is this possible to create build log file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coming in the next release of Cake (0.17.0) (which will hopefully we released at the end of this week) we implemented this [feature request](https://github.com/cake-build/cake/issues/703) which allows the usage of a new Extension Method which allows you to pass in an [MSBuildFileLogger](https://github.com/cake-build/cake/blob/develop/src/Cake.Common/Tools/MSBuild/MSBuildFileLogger.cs).  This extension method will prevent the need to go the ArgumentCustomization route.

This should allow you to something like:

```
MSBuild("./myproject.sln", new MSBuildSettings()
    .AddFileLogger(new MSBuildFileLogger {
        LogFile = "./errors.txt",
        MSBuildFileLoggerOutput = MSBuildFileLoggerOutput.ErrorsOnly   
});
```

You can get pre-release v0.17.0 version of Cake today using Cake's [MyGet feed](https://www.myget.org/gallery/cake).

If you're using nuget CLI to install Cake as is done in [default bootstrapper](https://github.com/cake-build/resources/blob/develop/build.ps1) you add `-Source https://www.myget.org/F/cake/api/v3/index.json` to the `nuget install` statement.

Then:

- If you're using a `package.config` to pin Cake version then specify version `0.17.0-alpha0092` or later.
- If you install just using `Cake` package id, then you either just add `-PreRelease` and it'll fetch the latest version from feed or also specify `-Version 0.17.0-alpha009` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [WithLogger(MSBuildSettings, ​string loggerAssembly, ​string loggerClass, ​string loggerParameters)](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.common.tools.msbuild/949206fc/9d825e74) MSBuildSettings extension method, which can be used to specify an custom MSBuild logging.

There's currently no available setting for the MSBuild standard file logger but you can still use that using the [ArgumentCustomization](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.core.tooling/d75cd243/60ae911b).

```
if(IsRunningOnWindows())
{
    DirectoryPath logPath = MakeAbsolute(Directory("./logfiles"));
    // Use MSBuild
    foreach(string currenproject in projectslocation)
    {
        FilePath logFile = logPath.CombineWithFilePath(string.Format(
                               "{0}.log",
                               currenproject));

        MSBuild(currenproject, new MSBuildSettings {
            ArgumentCustomization = args=>args.Append(
                "/flp:\"logfile={0};verbosity={1}\"",
                logFile.FullPath,
                Verbosity.Diagnostic
            )
        }.SetConfiguration(configuration)
        .SetVerbosity(Verbosity.Minimal));
    }
}
```

Comment: @vijay was this what you were looking for? It's a good question to please comment on anything's unclear and I'll try to clarify.